# VBox manager seeing but not seeing VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, virtualization

It might sound stupid but [that's preaty much it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDJVh.png)

I run `sudo VBoxManage setextradata Whonix-Workstation-XFCE1 "VBoxInternal/Devices/lsilogicsas/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/ReadOnly" 1`

and getting back next:

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Whonix-Workstation-XFCE1'
```

But on the other hand:

> VBoxManage list vms

```
"Whonix-Gateway-XFCE" {cac16b00-e3c6-41a7-8e91-302d4d38b84c}
"Whonix-Workstation-XFCE" {7b7b452a-8197-4f78-a5fa-3747e59d5578}
"Whonix-Workstation-XFCE1" {5ba1f377-a438-4de5-aa4f-5b5a3fae13a0}
```

I've tried to use UUID but no luck as well

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine with UUID {5ba1f377-a438-4de5-aa4f-5b5a3fae13a0}
```

Comment: The virtual HDD and their configuration file for these VMs actually exist on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Use `VBoxManage setextradata ...` without `sudo`.

Why:

I'm pretty sure, your problem is using sudo:
From the screenshot, *your* VMs are most likely owned and used by the user *jungleman*.
Therefore, `VBoxManage list vms` displays something.

But you issue the command `VBoxManage setextradata ...` using `sudo`, which means it tries to interact with the VMs of user `root`.

What is your output of `sudo VBoxManage list vms`?
If it's empty, there's your problem.